# PUT response code with 204

Tags: java, web-services, rest

My PUT and POST are same, so I am using PUT operation. Here I need to send response body data when PUT successful e.g. either new data insert into Cassandra or update existing record.

So, what response code should I use in this case.. code 204 I am using for successful PUT with response body, but it automatic convert into 200 code while testing with POSTMAN. so what should I use here.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3):

> If the target resource does not have a current representation and the
> PUT successfully creates one, then the origin server MUST inform the
> user agent by sending a 201 (Created) response.  If the target
> resource does have a current representation and that representation is
> successfully modified in accordance with the state of the enclosed
> representation, then the origin server MUST send either a 200 (OK) or
> a 204 (No Content) response to indicate successful completion of the
> request.

Based on this (and agreeing with Hank), if you have an entity with your response, you should use `201`.

Comment: Note that `204 No Content` should only be used if there is no entity returned. If the action resulted in a create and there is no content to return, it's unclear whether to return 201 or 204, but I would lean towards 201.

Comment: I have to send some data in response body in PUT operation then what status code I should use.. 204, 201, 200